# Eloquent ORM insert or update

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I'm working on a project using Laravel framework’s database component. This library includes a Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL) called “Capsule” and an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) library called “Eloquent”.

I want to update the extension already in DB, but I want also to insert a new "extension" if they don't exist. What is best way to do that?

My code so far:

```
try {
    $updatedDomainsCount = Capsule::table('tbldomainpricing')
        ->where('extension', $tld)
        ->update(
            [
                'extension' => $tld,
                'autoreg' => 'domenytv',
                'grace_period' => '15',

                 'idprotection' => $idp,
                  'grace_period_fee' => $rea_price,
            ]
        );

    echo "Updated {$updatedDomainsCount} TLD: $tld</br>";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "I couldn't update domains tld. {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Comment: I don't know abut the systems you are using but `insert...on duplicate update` should do what you want.

Comment: Fair warning that if you don't understand the basic syntax for SQL statements, using an ORM/DBAL will probably be more complex than literal sql statements.

Comment: Hey Krystian, I updated the question title, to be more relevant to people who know this stuff. I entered because I know MySQL but have no idea what Eloquent is. People who know Eloquent and not very good at SQL would have probably missed it. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 4):

Use Eloquent ORM method: `updateOrCreate`, use to create new record or updated existing.

[Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()Already try this. Looks like WHMCS don't implement this method."

Comment: When you create a modal which extend Eloquent model and then call the mentioned method, it will work.